# Maven and Java 17 - Which Maven Archetype supports Java 17 Development?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

#### Which Maven archetypes support Java 17, and how can I find archetypes which support Java 17?

This question comes about as I do not know which archetype I should choose when creating a Maven project with Eclipse. (The fact that I am using Eclipse is not particularly relevant other than to say it produces a long list of possible archetypes, and I currently have this filtered to "Internal".)

[image: eclipse Maven archetype]

##### The "default" option, often quoted in media on the web, is "maven-archetype-quickstart".

However I am aware that this does not support Java (language) Version 17, so I wonder if there is an alternative that I should be using instead?

Answer (score 0):

you can use maven-archetype-quickstart 1.4 version it's support web development with java 17

You can go through the Central maven Repository

[image]

Comment: Thanks - any idea how I would get Eclipse IDE to "know about" version 1.4? ie: If I currently have 1.1 available, how do I "upgrade" it?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Use the "Maven Central" catalog

Comment: @greg-449 How do I do that? Sorry my understanding of how to use these systems is quite limited as I am new-ish in Java world, and know essentially nothing about Maven, at least to a detailed level.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant you can follow these https://howtodoinjava.com/eclipse/how-to-import-maven-remote-archetype-catalogs-in-eclipse/

Comment: @omprakashK If I follow the instructions on that page exactly, then I get an error: "Remote Catalog is empty"

Comment: you will try click on refresh button to update local repository

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant i have added one pic go through that

Comment: I don't appear to have a "refresh" button, where is this?

Comment: On catalog Dropdown box select that url then in filter you can type maven-archetype-quickstart

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant According to the screenshot in your question, you chosen as _Catalog_ _Internal_ instead of _All Catalogs_ or _Maven Central_.

Comment: i didn't choosen internal, i choosen as a maven central path

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what you mean by "support". Eclipse and Maven both use Java to run. If neither supported it, you'd have already gotten errors.

When the code generates, you can add property `maven.compiler.target` to be `17`, if you wish

Comment: Not all artifacts support target/source version 17. Please **read the question**.

Comment: Please stop accusing people of not reading. Explain what you mean by "support"

Comment: Written in the [Maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html#java-9-or-later), it is the compiler plugin that you need to change. This has very little to do with archetypes, but there are others available online that do claim to "support" (has in, come **bundled with**) an updated compiler plugin, or property set to `17` - https://github.com/dominikcebula/java17-basic-archetype

Comment: `maven-archetype-quickstart` Version 1.1 does **not** support Java 17.

Comment: Okay, cool. [The latest is 1.4, by the way](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart), and has not been updated since Java 17 was released, so sure, none are going to work with Java 17 out of the box. Back to your question - "Which one does support it", I just linked to one in the above comment.

Comment: Actually, 1.4 **does** work with Java 17